# DHCP Troubleshooting

Tags: dhcp, troubleshooting

I am working at a branch office and have been tasked with changing out the DHCP scope to match the overall corporate IP address scheme.  The main office assigned me an IP address range of 192.168.0.200 through 192.168.0.225.  I changed the scope on Friday afternoon and came in on Monday morning to discover that only some of the workstations had picked up new leases from the new DHCP scope.  Any ideas as to what may be happening, what I might check or adjust?

Comment: This guy hat the *exact* same question: http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-392956/analyze-dhcp-configuration-options

Answer (score 3):

Basically Time-To-Live. If you had the original scope set with a 7 day lease time, the clients will not try for a new IP until the half life of their current lease is reached (3.5days). If you had clients renew their IPs on friday before you changed the scope they may not renew again until tomorrow some time.

Edit: horrible flow & grammer